# How do I restore the movement animation in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I recently installed some mods for Skyrim, but I have screwed up somewhere, and now, I have no walking or running animation.

The characters are standing straight with their hands out to the side. I have tried disabling and even removing the mods, yet, nothing happens.

I have even reinstalled Skyrim, but, that hasn't done anything either. I'm at a loss here. If anyone knows what's wrong, please help me out!

Comment: Have you tried going into sneak mode then out again?  Sometimes even on a PS3 copy of the game I end up in glide mode!

Comment: Have you tried with a new save?

Answer (score 3):

Was one of the mods you installed Fores New Idles? If so, you'll need to generate the behaviors again:

> Start Data/tools/GenerateFNIS_for_Users/GenerateFNISforUsers.exe AS ADMINISTRATOR (part of FNIS Behavior, and ABSOLUTELY NECESSARY, or NOTHING works)

Source: FNIS Skyrim Nexus page

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have a file named defaultmale.hkx in the folder
Steam\steamapps\common\Skyrim\Data\meshes\actors\character\character assets